# Dependency Injection Container and defining all(?) dependencies

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am puzzled about where to define all my dependencies.

It seems like a huge overkill to load every possible dependency while it may actually not be used at all. Defining them at place of need would result in code duplication.

Where would anything be defined? With perhaps a configuration of a dependency to be initiated once? For example a Logger or DB connection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my work we had a problem like that and we used an approach based on Symfony2. We have a simple Dependency Container, which holds lambda functions used to actually create the dependencies we might need and, upon first usage, the factory is called.

Something like:

```
DC['AFactory'] = function() { return new A(); };
```

DC has a "cache" of dependency objects, so every time you use something like DC->get('A'), we first check whether the caché is filled, in which case, you get the existent instance, otherwhise, the factory function is called, stored in cache and then you get the results. This way we don't have to load every possible dependency until it's actually used.